# How to resize the card using CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


.card {
    /* Add shadows to create the "card" effect */
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 100%;
}

.card:hover {
   box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit-no" />
    <title>HRIS - Yokogawa Techno Philippines Inc.</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link href="~/Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <center>
                <img class="d-block" src="" alt="icon">
                <h2>HRIS</h2>
            </center>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="card-title"><strong>Welcome</strong></div>
                            <p><small>Sign in to your Account</small></p>
                            <hr />
                            <div class="form-horizontal">



                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
                                        <input type="submit" id="cmdLogin" class="btn btn-group btn btn-info" value="Login" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <h6>Forgot Password? Reset it <a type="submit">here</a>.</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



    
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to resize the card on my HTML and CSS.

But I am having a problem if I set the `width` and resize the window. there is a horizontal scrollbar showing up.

my main goal is to make the card smaller and place it in the center of the window, also after resizing the window I would like to make it responsive. I am new in front-end development so I am totally lost. Hope someone could help me.

The main problem is the size of the card is too large. it fits on the 12 columns of the bootstrap.

I want to place it in the center with a column size of 6 in bootstrap. is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy with bootstrap. You need to change col-md-12 to col-md-6 and add offset.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


.card {
    /* Add shadows to create the "card" effect */
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 100%;
}

.card:hover {
   box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit-no" />
    <title>HRIS - Yokogawa Techno Philippines Inc.</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link href="~/Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <center>
                <img class="d-block" src="" alt="icon">
                <h2>HRIS</h2>
            </center>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="card-title"><strong>Welcome</strong></div>
                            <p><small>Sign in to your Account</small></p>
                            <hr />
                            <div class="form-horizontal">



                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
                                        <input type="submit" id="cmdLogin" class="btn btn-group btn btn-info" value="Login" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <h6>Forgot Password? Reset it <a type="submit">here</a>.</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



    
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```